# Showing that $f$ is not Absolutely continuous

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, continuity, lebesgue-integral, bounded-variation

Frist:- I am not sure about what title this question should be.

Suppose the function $f:[0,\frac{1}{2}]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ defined by

$$
f(x) =
\begin{cases}
0, & \text{if }x=0 \\
x \cos(\frac{\pi}{x}), & \text{if } x\in(0,\frac{1}{2}]
\end{cases}
$$
I want to prove that there is no Lebesuge integrable function $g$ such that :-
$$f(x)=\int_{[0,x]} g \, dm$$

this is the lemma form my note in which I want to use it

> Let $f\in L^{1}[a,b]$. Define a new functions $g:[a,b]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}. g(x)=\int_{a}^{x}f(y)\, dy$. Then $g\in AC$.

My attempt:- 
I try to show that f is not absolutely continuous since in case $f$ is absolutely continuous the function g will exist ( there is a theorem I am not sure if they have name or not ).
So I was able to show that f is not Bounded Variation, but this is not enough since family of BV is larger than family AC.

Comment: You have it backwards: if you've shown that $f$ is not BV then you have also shown it is not AC. The reverse is what doesn't hold (there are BV functions that are not AC; indeed there are continuous BV functions that are not AC).

Comment: Also, the existence of $g$ that you have mentioned is usually considered half of the Lebesgue fundamental theorem of calculus. The more general result which has the same consequences in the Lebesgue case is the Radon-Nikodym theorem.

Comment: You are right,I am just confused, about that.but I think my problem still have issue.

Comment: Consider a partition formed by the points ${1 \over k}$ for $k=1,...,n$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It basically oscillates too fast. We can identify points where the function is large by looking at the extrema of the $\cos(\pi/x)$ part. Specifically, consider a finite sequence $1/2,1/3,1/4,\dots,1/n$, the function values there are $1/2$, $-1/3$, $1/4$, $-1/5$, ..., $(-1)^n/n$. So for $n>2$, the total variation on $[1/n,1/2]$ is at least $\sum_{k=3}^n \left ( \frac{1}{k} + \frac{1}{k-1} \right )$, which diverges as $n \to \infty$. Hence $f$ is not BV, which implies it cannot be AC either.

Comment: I am still confused with how to apply FTC with our result ($f$ is not AC). can you explain how to apply it.

Comment: FTC's not relevant; I'm just showing that $f$ is not BV from the definition. My previous comment was tangential: the statement "if $f$ is AC then $f(x) = \int_0^x f'(y) dm(y)$" is part of the FTC in the Lebesgue theory. I mentioned this because you asked about it briefly in the OP, but it's not needed to solve the problem.